# Show text with after 3 sec with setTimeOut in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

For React JS
I need to show a text in

after 2 seconds, it's work in console but not in the DOM

```
  const items = document.getElementById("items");
```

```
  const errorDisplay = () => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      items.innerHTML = "please wait..";
      console.log(items);
    }, 2000);
  };
```

```
  <p id="items">  </p>
```

Thanks

```
  const items = document.getElementById("items");

  const errorDisplay = () => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      items.innerHTML = "please wait..";
      console.log(items);
    }, 2000);
  };

 <p id="items"> </p>
```

Comment: You can use ```useState()```, hook it will update automatically, when value changes.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `errorDisplay` now in your React code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show a please wait paragraph for two seconds before displaying the products you can do something like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];

export default function App() {
const [isWaiting, setIsWaiting] = useState(true);

const productsListItems = items.map((item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.id}</li>);

useEffect(() => {
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
  setIsWaiting(false);

  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
 }, [2000]);
}, []);

return (
<div className="App">
  {isWaiting && <p>Please wait...</p>}
  {!isWaiting && <ul>{productsListItems}</ul>}
</div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example of React app with `setState` for controlling the visibility of the wait text, and `useEffect` to use the `setTimeout` function:

HTML:

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

function App() {
  const [showWait, setShowWait] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowWait(true);
      console.log("please wait ...");
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return showWait && <p>please wait...</p>;
}

root.render(<App></App>);
```

See https://codepen.io/michaeljoh/pen/RweVBpJ

Answer (score 1):

Or refactor the returning jsx to this depending on your readability preferences:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];

export default function App() {
const [isWaiting, setIsWaiting] = useState(true);

const productsListItems = items.map((item) => <li>{item.id}</li>);

const output = isWaiting ? <p>Please wait...</p> : <ul>{productsListItems}</ul>

useEffect(() => {
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
  setIsWaiting(false);

  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
 }, [2000]);
}, []);

return <div className="App">{output}</div>;
}
```